# unable to stop test with runner.storp.run method

Tags: nunit

I am trying to run the nunit test programmatically which I have successfully done. but I also wants to stop the test whenever I need to but runner.stoprun is not stopping the test run. can someone please help with the same.

following is the code snippet which is running the test:

```
IDictionary<String, Object> options = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
options.Add(FrameworkPackageSettings.DefaultTestNamePattern, testName);

DefaultTestAssemblyBuilder builder = new NUnit.Framework.Api.DefaultTestAssemblyBuilder();
ITest test=builder.Build(asmName, options);
runner = new NUnit.Framework.Api.NUnitTestAssemblyRunner(builder);
runner.Load(asmName, options);
runner.Run(null, TestFilter.Empty);
```

and with following code I am trying to stop the test in a different thread:

```
if (runner.IsTestRunning)
    runner.StopRun(true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a different thread. Different from the test thread? Different from the thread that called Run?

In any case, the Run method you are calling is synchronous, so the test will keep that thread busy till it returns.

Since you are using NUnit internal methods (i.e. not designed for public consumption even though visible) you should probably be using a debug build of NUnit so that you can step into the call to StopRun.

Essentially, there are two possibilities:
1. The setup you have created for running tests is wrong.
2. One of the tests is refusing to be terminated.

I'd rule out the second item first, by using a very simple test.

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for your reply. Sorry for the delay in my reply. Can you please tell me how to take debug build of nunit for this to check why it is not working.

Comment: We don't distribute a debug build so you would have to download the source and build it yourself. The Building.md document will tell you how to proceed.

Comment: Building NUnit yourself is, of course, a somewhat advanced approach compared to simply writing tests. But then, calling NUnit programmatically is similarly advanced, so I assume you're up for it. :-)